# Scala: get rid of nested pattern matching over options

Tags: scala

I have four objects typed as `Option[Int]` and I want to get the first one that is not None.

For the moment, the shorter way I have found, instead of nested pattern matching (`case None => case Some() => etc`) is this:

```
val a = None
val b = Some(1)
val c = Some(2)
val d = None

Seq(a, b, c, d).flatten.headOption
```

But I wonder if there is a more idiomatic way of doing this in scala, maybe with a for comprehension.

Comment: `Seq(a, b, c, d).collect{case Some(a) => a}.head`

Comment: @Jus12 `Seq(a, b, c, d).collectFirst{case Some(e) => e}`

Comment: `Seq(a, b, c, d).find(_.nonEmpty).flatten` ?